# How do I remove a user input that has been stored in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, variables, user-input

Pretend that I'm asking the user to input an album to list down.
I have this fine, 
but for some reason I cant figure out a way for them to be able  to then delete the input that they have made.

This is the method that I have used to store any album input that they have

```
static void InsertNewAlbum()
{
    //Variable for user input
    string albumInput

    //Ask for the user for details 
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the Title of the album you would like to store");
    albumInput = Console.ReadLine();

    //Process the input of the user to make it easier to search later on
    albumInput = albumInput.ToUpper();
    albumInput = albumInput.Trim();

    //Find an empty spot within list
    int nextAvailableSpace = FindSlot("");
    if (nextAvailableSpace != -1)
    {
        //Put customer information within an empty slot into the car park
        albumNames[nextAvailableSpace] = albumInput;
    }
    else
    {
        //Inform that the usercannot park as the parking space is full
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry, but there are no available spaces left to store your       album.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Here's the how the "FindSlot" method goes, for anyone that curious

```
static int FindSlot(string albumName)
//Finding an empty slot for the user to put their car in
{
    int result = - 1;
    for (int index = 0; index < albumNames.Length; index++)
    {
        if (albumNames[index] == albumNames)
        {
            result = index;
            break;
        }

        else if (albumName == "" && albumNames[index] == null)
        {
            result = index;
            break;

        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

albumNames is the string that it puts in album the customer puts in and it's a static string.

So yeah, the user can freely put in 10 albums, but when it comes to deleting an album I get stuck.
The album is listen within a string array. I've tried various things within my knowledge but nothing seems to be working.

Thanks for anyone that can help, it is quite complicated.

Comment: so you need a different function in which you will read an album name and delete it if it's present in the albumNames, am I right?

Comment: Is it possible to use list instead of array?

Comment: Not related to the question, but is "int nextAvailableSpace = FindSlot("");"  correct? should that be "int nextAvailableSpace = FindSlot( albumInput );

Comment: yes, that's write do you know a way perhaps? @IsThatSo

Answer (score 0):

You always send `""` to `FindSlot`, as you should be sending the `albumInput`. If you need to know if the album is present, first control all the `albumNames` if your input is present, then look for a space. Like:

```
static int FindSlot(string albumName)
//Finding an empty slot for the user to put their car in
{
    for (int index = 0; index < albumNames.Length; index++)
    {
        if (albumNames[index] == albumName)
        {
            return index;
        }
    }

    for (int index = 0; index < albumNames.Length; index++)
    {
        if (albumNames[index] == "")
        {
            albumNames[index] = albumName;
            return index;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

And call it like:

```
static void InsertNewAlbum()
{
    //Variable for user input
    string albumInput;

    //Ask for the user for details 
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the Title of the album you would like to store");
    albumInput = Console.ReadLine();

    //Process the input of the user to make it easier to search later on
    albumInput = albumInput.ToUpper();
    albumInput = albumInput.Trim();

    //Find an empty spot within list
    int nextAvailableSpace = FindSlot(albumInput);
    if (nextAvailableSpace != -1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(albumInput + " is stored successfully at slot" + nexAvailableSpace + "");
    }
    else
    {
        //Inform that the usercannot park as the parking space is full
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry, but there are no available spaces left to store your       album.");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

To delete; you can use a similar function:

```
static int DeleteAlbum(string albumName)
//Finding an empty slot for the user to put their car in
{
    for (int index = 0; index < albumNames.Length; index++)
    {
        if (albumNames[index] == albumName)
        {
            albumNames[index] = "";
            return index;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

As your `FindSlot` function, you can return an integer to confirm deletion was successful. Like:

```
static void DeleteAnAlbum()
{
    //Variable for user input
    string albumInput;

    //Ask for the user for details 
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the Title of the album you would like to store");
    albumInput = Console.ReadLine();

    //Process the input of the user to make it easier to search later on
    albumInput = albumInput.ToUpper();
    albumInput = albumInput.Trim();

    //Find and delete the album from the List
    int deletedIndex = DeleteAlbum(albumInput);
    if (deletedIndex != -1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(albumInput + " is deleted successfully");    
        }
    else
    {
        //Inform that the usercannot delete
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry, but there are no albums with given name.");
    }
        Console.ReadLine();
}
```

This code is not good, but I tried to keep your style.